# Typing a generic websocket handler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, websocket, typescript-generics

I'm trying to find the best way to handle typing a generic websocket handler. The implementation of the existing handler looks something like this:

```
type WSMessage = {
    type: string;
    [key: string]: unknown;
}
type HandlerFunc = (data: WSMessage) => void;

class PersistentWebsocket {
    subscriptions = {};

    initializeWebsocket(): void {
        this.socket.onmessage = (event) => {
            this.processMessage(JSON.parse(event.data) as WSMessage);
        };
    }

    processMessage(message: WSMessage): void {
        for(const handler of this.subscriptions[message.type] || []) {
            handler(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I then have a hook that uses this websocket:

```
export function useWebsocketSubscription(
    websocket: PersistentWebsocket,
    type: string,
    handler: HandlerFunc,
): void {
    useEffect(() => {
        websocket.subscribe(type, handler);
        return () => {
            websocket.unsubscribe(type, handler);
        };
    });
}
```

called like so:

```
useWebsocketSubscription(websocket, "use-search-results", (data) => {           
    const d = (data as unknown) as PlannerTypes.SearchResults;                  
    setActivityOptions(d.results.activities);                                   
    setLocationOptions(d.results.locations);                                    
    setMode(DisplayMode.search);                                                
});
```

I'd really like to be able to remove the `data as unknown as ActualType` declaration, but I can't figure out how to write generics that would let me define the handler function passing in the interface that the websocket message will conform to. Everything either complains because WSMessage might not have the keys that the more specific message expects, or results in syntax errors, or typescript not liking me accessing `message.type` in the `PersistentWebsocket` class.

Is there a way to get this to work, or am I stuck with the nasty typecast/assertion in every handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what `PlannerTypes.SearchResults`, so I'm not sure why you need to do `(data as unknown) as PlannerTypes.SearchResults`. If `PlannerTypes.SearchResults` is a sub-type of `WSMessage` (as it should be), you should be able to do just `data as PlannerTypes.SearchResults`.

If you want to avoid the cast every time you have a hook, you can write [overloaded declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for every websocket type:

```
export function useWebsocketSubscription(
    websocket: PersistentWebsocket, 
    type: "use-search-results", 
    handler: (data: PlannerTypes.SearchResults) => void
): void;
export function useWebsocketSubscription(
    websocket: PersistentWebsocket, 
    type: string, 
    handler: HandlerFunc
): void { 
 ... definition ...
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're right, I didn't need the as unknown part. It's a little frustrating that the only way to avoid the cast inside each method is to overload the declarations, since the websocket code shouldn't know what the handler types take, but I guess it's not that big a problem in the scheme of things.